# Resharper does wrong tabbing on switch case

Tags: c#, resharper

Since I've been using **Resharper** I have always noticed this bug, though I do the right tabbing, after writing a new line or pasting a piece of code, resharper moves the underlying line two tabs away, like in this situation:
[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What are the exact repro steps to get the issue above? Did you simply hit `[Enter]` after typing the previous line? It seem strange that the two indented sections are separated by a line of code that is indented properly.

Comment: @RufusL I am sure that it's an intellisense (resharper) issue because if I manually type code without letting resharper do refactoring (like on paste) nothing happens.

Comment: So if I go above any line of code inside the `case` statement and paste something or do #region, the underlying line tabs two places away

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you delete and re-type the closing curly brace `}` for the `case` block?

Comment: @RufusL Everything tabs correctly.

Comment: Also if I press `[ENTER]` after the closing curly brace of the `case` statement, then it wraps with an extra tab instead of two (while it shouldn't do even one extra tab).

Comment: And that resolves the issue? You can now add a new line with the correct tab? Have you tried deleting and re-typing the last `}` in the file (or holding down CTRL and then pressing A then K then F) to format the whole document? After doing this, is the issue resolved? I have a feeling that your whole method may be indented incorrectly, so when you add new lines it's indenting them to the proper position within the namespace.

Comment: Document format produced this result https://imgur.com/a/iGElBdB

Comment: Method signature here https://imgur.com/a/YUdzNLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you may have the braces layout for case lables set to "At next line indented 2 (GNU style):

[image]

To fix this, go to the `ReSharper` menu, choose "Options", and then navigate to:

`Code Editing --> C# --> Braces Layout --> Block under "case" label`

And change the Preference to: `At next line (BSD style)`:

[image]

You also may need to check your Visual Studio Settings:

`Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Formatting --> Indentation`

[image]

Comment: I've set it to At next line (BSD style) but after CTRL K, CTRL F this is the result of format https://imgur.com/a/bfMAAXb . May it be that C#'s intellisense is still activated?

Comment: Even after editing the Preference no changes apply. Set it to 2, one, but nothing changes. The result is still the same

Comment: Have you checked your visual studio settings? I added an image at the bottom of the answer if that helps.

Comment: They're set just as in the picture you uploaded.